# HT access file not redirecting

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, web

According to my PHP information i have the following mod activated:

```
mod_rewrite
```

I have the following rule in my .htacess file

```
    RewriteRule    ^dev/bloglic_script.js   dev/bloglicscriptreplacer.php?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&ref=%{HTTP_REFERER}&country=DK
```

But when i try to view the code i get the following error:

```
    script src="dev/bloglic_script.js" type="text/javascript">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /bloglic-2013/dev/bloglic_script.js was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what i am missing?

My entire Htacess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^dl/bloglic_script.js   dl/bloglicscriptreplacer.php?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&ref=%{HTTP_REFERER}&country=DK
    RewriteRule    ^dev/bloglic_script.js   dev/bloglicscriptreplacer.php?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&ref=%{HTTP_REFERER}&country=DK
    RewriteRule    ^cake/index.php/tags/addTag   cake/index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&website=%{HTTP_REFERER} [L]
    RewriteRule    ^cake/index.php/tags/deleteTag   cake/index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&website=%{HTTP_REFERER} [L]
    RewriteRule    ^script/bloglic_script.js   script/scriptreplacer.php?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&ref=%{HTTP_REFERER}
#    RewriteCond     %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  MSIE
#    RewriteRule    ^script/bloglic_script.js   script/scriptreplacer.php?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&ref=%{HTTP_REFERER}&ie=1

  #  RewriteRule    ^$ cake/index.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING}
</IfModule>
```

**Update**

Changed around in my files and now im getting the following error:

```
    <script src="dev/bloglic_script.js" type="text/javascript">
Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost/bloglic-2013/dev/bloglic_script.js
</script>
```

However no matter how much i refresh it still does not work

Comment: Is the absolute url you are trying to mimic `htt://yourdomain.com/bloglic-2013/dev/bloglic_script.js`?  And can you post your entire .htaccess file?

Comment: @miah added my full htacess code

Comment: What is the absolute url where you expect the script to live? `http://localhost/bloglic-2013/dev/bloglic_script.js`  or is it `http://localhost/dev/bloglic_script.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `/bloglic-2013/dev/bloglic_script.js` will not trigger this rule because the `^` means from the beginning, and in this instance, the beginning is `bloglic-2013`, not `dev`

If you change the rule to include the leading directory it should trigger.  You'll just need to make sure that the rewritten path is correct.

```
RewriteRule    ^bloglic-2013/dev/bloglic_script.js   dev/bloglicscriptreplacer.php?ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR}&ref=%{HTTP_REFERER}&country=DK
```

Comment: Saldy this did not work if i replace your string with mine the site doesnt even load

Comment: i made it load now but now i get the following error message:
<p>The requested URL /bloglic-2013/dev/bloglic_script.js was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>